# Counting characters in a string by dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c

I am writing a C program where I write a function to count the number of character in a function. I have to use a dynamic memory allocation to allocate memory for an array take the array and copy it to another with fixed size. I have wrote the following code for it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int count_insensitive(char *str, char ch){
    int n = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
        if (tolower(*(str+i))== tolower(ch)){
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
int main(){
    char *a,ch;
    int i,n;
    n=50;
    a = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
    if (a==NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
    char str[strlen(a)];
    strcpy(str,a);
    free(a);
    char c[] = {'b','H','8','u','$'};
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        ch = c[i];
        printf("The character '%c' occurs %d times.\n",c[i],count_insensitive(str,ch));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program runs  but it take only the first 3 characters of a string and prints the position. Can you help me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `char str[strlen(a)];` -->  `char str[strlen(a)+1];`  Make room for the null terminating character.

Comment: `sizeof(a)` is just the size of a pointer.  You probably want to use `n` instead.

Answer (score 2):

From [**`fgets()`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

where `num` is the second argument passed to `fgets()`.

In your code, you are passing `sizeof(a)` as second argument to `fgets()`:

```
fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
```

and `a` is `char` pointer.

The size of pointer will be `4` byte on a 32-bit system and `8` on a 64-bit system.

Seems that yours is 32-bit system and you must be giving input of more that `4` characters, that's why `fgets()` is reading only first `3` characters of the given input.

Since, you are allocating memory of `n` characters to pointer `a`, you should pass `n` as second argument to `fgets()`:

```
fgets(a, n, stdin);
```

Also, `strlen()` returns length of a null terminated string without including the terminating null character itself. So, you should add `1` to `strlen(a)` to ensure that `str` should be long enough to accommodate null terminating character:

```
char str[strlen(a)+1];
                  ^^
```